# Resque Job: "Could not create the Java virtual machine."

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, apache-tika

I'm running a resque job which contains following line:

```
temp = %x(/usr/bin/java -jar /usr/local/tika/tika-app-1.0.jar -t /tmp/myfile.txt)
```

Whenever my job tries to execute that line, I get the message:

```
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

When I execute the code not as a job but as a normal ruby script, that line works.

Unfortunately, there is no further hint on what the problem could be. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your job is executing in root environment and you haven't set JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: How can I check in which environment the job is running? I run the workers as user "rails" so I guess that the environment of that user is used.

Comment: sudo su. sudo rails. env | grep JAVA_HOME

Comment: Or find the rake command and add the JAVA_HOME=.. just after rake.

Comment: for the "rails" user, JAVA_HOME is also not set and the command works without a problem.

Comment: If it's not the env, have you try to tune the JVM with -Xmx512m ?

Comment: This was it, I had to set the -Xmx512m. Thank you very much!